# AWS Lambda access Neptune on the same VPC

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have the following lambda code to try to access Neptune from the same VPC on AWS. Which most copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-python.html.

But I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

The source code:

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

wss = 'wss://{}:{}/gremlin'.format(host, port)
remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection(wss, 'g')
print("wss--> {}".format(wss))

# grapch
graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)

# get
info = g.V().hasLabel('my').outE().inV().path().toList()
print(info)
return info
```

Error traceback:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "HTTP 403: Forbidden",
  "errorType": "HTTPClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py\", line 58, in toList\n    return list(iter(self))\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py\", line 48, in __next__\n    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py\", line 573, in apply_strategies\n    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connection.py\", line 149, in apply\n    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote_connection.py\", line 56, in submit\n    result_set = self._client.submit(bytecode, request_options=self._extract_request_options(bytecode))\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/client.py\", line 127, in submit\n    return self.submitAsync(message, bindings=bindings, request_options=request_options).result()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/client.py\", line 148, in submitAsync\n    return conn.write(message)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py\", line 55, in write\n    self.connect()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py\", line 45, in connect\n    self._transport.connect(self._url, self._headers)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py\", line 40, in connect\n    self._ws = self._loop.run_sync(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/tornado/ioloop.py\", line 576, in run_sync\n    return future_cell[0].result()\n"
  ]
```

Comment: That's interesting... A 403 error normally means "connected but denied". The [Using Python to connect to a Neptune DB instance - Amazon Neptune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-python.html) example you reference has no mention of authentication or security. Yet [Example: Connecting to Neptune Using Python with Signature Version 4 Signing - Amazon Neptune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-python.html) has lots of code for authentication. I wonder whether authentication is something you can turn on/off?

Comment: Does your Neptune cluster have IAM Authentication enabled? If it does you will need to sign the connection request using SigV4 credentials.